# Launch Whatsapp Business from Flutter

Tags: flutter, whatsapp, url-launcher

I am trying to launch WhatsApp Business app using Flutter and have written below code:

```
whatsAppBusiness(phone) {
  print(phone);
  return launchUrl(
    Uri.parse(
      'whatsapp-business://send?phone=$phone',
      // 'https://api.whatsapp.com/$phone', //put your number here
    ),
  );
}
```

but it is not getting launched.

Comment: I tried to type "whatsapp://" in browser & it open WhatsApp messenger app. But when I install WhatsApp Business, it open WhatsApp Business, not WhatsApp messenger. That's strange. You may consider change url to `'whatsapp://send?phone=$phone',`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question because there're 2 kinds of WhatsApp. Here what I've tried:

When my phone have only WA Messenger, I tried to type "whatsapp://" in Safari & it open WA Messenger app. But when I install more WA Business, this "whatsapp://" open WA Business.

I go to WA document: https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934, it tells us to use deep linking like this: `https://wa.me/{phone}?text={text}`. I followed it & it open WA Messenger!

OK so what come to conclusion? If your phone contains 2 WA apps:

- To open WA Business: `"whatsapp://send?phone=$phone"`
- To open WA Messenger: use deep linking (reference above) `https://wa.me/{phone}?text={text}`
- To open WA but don't care what kind of it: just use `"whatsapp://send?phone=$phone"`

P/s: Your `whatsapp-business://` not working, maybe because it doesn't exist?!

P/s 2: Don't forget to config `info.plist` & Android manifest as [url launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) requires.

Comment: I am already using  "whatsapp://send?phone=$phone" to launch WhatsApp Messenger and tried multiple things to launch WhatsApp Business including what you suggested, but non is working.

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify whatsapp business.

just open **whatsapp**.

if you have both apps installed (whatsapp, whatsapp business), you will be given the choice of which one to open

so, just open whatsapp, here an example:

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                String phone = '123';
                String infoText = 'blabla';
                String whatsappUrl =
                    "whatsapp://send?phone=$phone" "&text=${Uri.encodeFull(infoText)}";
                try {
                  launchUrlString(whatsappUrl);
                } catch (e) {
                  //handle error properly
                }
              },
              child: const Text('whatsapp'),
            )
```

Comment: I am not getting such option. As both the apps are installed in my app, it is directly launching WhatsApp Messenger but not the WhatsApp Business.

Comment: please can you provide further details? such versions, devices, platforms etc

Comment: Using android device, Galaxy M32s with Android 11 OS